# Split section into multiple memory regions

Tags: c, ld, cortex-m

I'm developing an application on an ARM Cortex-M microcontroller which has two RAM banks à 64kB. The first bank is directly followed by the second bank in the memory map.

The memory banks are currently split into two regions in my linker script. The first region contains the sections `.bss` and `.data`. The second bank is used for `.heap` and `.stack`, which only take 1kB each (I'm using a different stack in FreeRTOS, which also manages it's own heap).

My problem is, that `.bss` is too large for the first bank. Therefore I'd like to move some of it's content to the second bank.

One way to accomplish this would be to create a new section, lets call it `.secondbss`, which is linked to the second bank. Single variables could then be added to this section using `__attribute__((section(".secondbss")))`.

The reasons why I am not using this solution are

- I really want to maintain portability of my source code
- There might be a whole lot of variables that would require this attribute and I don't want to choose the section for every single variable

Is there a better solution for this? I already thought of both memories as one region, but I don't know how to prevent the linker from misaligning the data across the boundary between both banks.

How can I solve my problem without using `__attribute__` flags?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you have 2 banks at `0x20000000` and `0x20010000`. You wants use Bank2 for heap and (main) stack. I assume that you have large `.bss` because of `configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE` in *FreeRTOSConfig.h*. Now see heap sources in *FreeRTOS/Source/portable/MemMang/*. There are 5 implementations of `pvPortMalloc()` that do memory allocation.

Looks at lines in *heap_X.c* that you use

```
/* Allocate the memory for the heap. */
#if( configAPPLICATION_ALLOCATED_HEAP == 1 )
    /* The application writer has already defined the array used for the RTOS
    heap - probably so it can be placed in a special segment or address. */
    extern uint8_t ucHeap[ configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE ];
#else
    static uint8_t ucHeap[ configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE ];
#endif /* configAPPLICATION_ALLOCATED_HEAP */
```

So you can set `configAPPLICATION_ALLOCATED_HEAP` at 1 and say to you linker to place `ucHeap` at `0x20010000`.

Another way is writing headers for each device that includes addresses of heap and stack and edit sources.
For *heap_1.c* we can do next changes:

```
// somewhere in devconfig.h
#define HEAP_ADDR   0x20010000

// in heap_1.c
// remove code related ucHeap
//
// remove static uint8_t *pucAlignedHeap = NULL;
// and paste:
static uint8_t *pucAlignedHeap = (uint8_t *)HEAP_ADDR;
```

For *heap_2.c* and *heap_4.c* edit function `prvHeapInit()` as well.

Pay attention to *heap_5.c* that includes `vPortDefineHeapRegions()`.

Now `pvPortMalloc()` will returns pointers to memory in Bank2. `pvPortMalloc()` used for allocations stacks of tasks, TCB and user varables. Read sources. Location of main stack depends of your device/architecture. For stm32 (ARM) see vector table or how to change MSP register.

Comment: Okay, thank you. This already helps a lot. But isn't there a way to tell the linker to use both banks for the same section? Although this should fix my current problem, I would like to know how to use both banks as if there was no boundary in between. In my eyes this should just be an alignment issue.

Comment: [There](https://answers.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+question/223976) is a similar problem with the sections. "So  you can just MANUALLY place specific object files."

Comment: `.bss2 (NOLOAD) : ALIGN(4) { foo.o(.bss .bss.*) } >RAM2`

All `.bss` data from _foo.o_ will be places into RAM2. Keep attention that you should fill this memory with zeros at startup as regular `.bss` section.